# Is it possible to add CSS in the Mail function in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, css, function, email

I want to add some css in the Mail function to this code:

```
$text .= "<h1>Confirmation Code</h1>";
$text .= "<img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/587949417577066499/3uCD4xxY_400x400.jpg'></img>";
$text .= "<h3>This is your confirmation code. Enter it into the text box in World Web. Here is the code: '".$_REQUEST['random_num']."'</h3>";
$text .= "<h4>Thank you for working with WWW. We appreciate the help!</h4>";
$text .= "</body></html>";
$subject = "Confirmation Code";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$to = $_REQUEST['email'];
mail($to, $subject, $text, $headers);
```

But when I add:

```
style="color: red;"
```

Or:

```
style="background-color: blue;"
```

It errors out. Anybody know how I can add css to the mail function in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not escaping the `"` within the `"`

try:

```php
$text .= "<h1 style='color:red;'>Confirmation Code</h1>";
//or
$text .= "<h1 style=\"color:red;\">Confirmation Code</h1>";
```